# Problem with URL in CMake ExternalProject_Add

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have a problem with executing ExternalProject_Add command in CMake. It says: At least one entry of URL is a path (invalid in a list).

I know that this error occurs when in the URL there is any semicolon, but I don't have any in my URL.

```
SET (Boost_Bootstrap_Command ./bootstrap.sh)
SET (Boost_b2_Command ./b2)
SET (Boost_URL https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.69.0/source/boost_1_69_0.tar.gz)
ExternalProject_Add(boost
    URL ${Boost_URL}
    URL_HASH_SHA256=9a2c2819310839ea373f42d69e733c339b4e9a19deab6bfec448281554aa4dbb
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    PATCH_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${Boost_Bootstrap_Command}
    BUILD_COMMAND ${Boost_b2_Command} install
    --with-thread
    --without-python
    --without-mpi
    --disable-icu
    --prefix=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/INSTALL
    --threading=single,multi
    --link=shared
    --variant=release
    -j8
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/INSTALL
)
```

Does anybody know what is the problem with my URL?

Comment: Please try placing this line: `BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1` between your `URL ${Boost_URL}` line and your `URL_HASH_SHA256` line and advise what happens.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher that did the trick :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS the documentation says, you need a download location for CMake to build the external project. When you don't download the package, the location is already there, but if you ask it from URL or git or something else, you have to provide `DOWNLOAD_DIR`.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my issue, too. I don't understand how `At least one entry of URL is a path (invalid in a list)` error message corresponds to that though. Why that message?